# JasperReports CategoryDataset has less data than expected?

Tags: graph, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to develop a ChartCustomizer that takes the data from a chart and converts it into a histogram (because JR does not directly support histograms). It's a fairly simple implementation with hard-coded intervals, etc. mostly as a proof-of-concept at this point.

The data I'm analyzing is HTTP response-time data of the form [date, response-time] and I have a CSV file with 18512 records in it. In my summary band, I have 3 items:

1. A text field dumping `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` (it reports 18512 in iReport's report preview)
2. A time series showing all the data points [date, response-time]
3. A category plot containing all the data points in a single series [category=`$F{DATE}`, value=`$F{RESPONSE_TIME}`]

I decided that the most straightforward way to build a histogram would be to use the Category plot because it had the right structure for the final histogram chart.

When the `ChartCustomizer` runs, it dumps out all kinds of good information about the data set, including the size. Strangely, the size is 10252: it's missing something like 8000 data points. I can't understand why the category plot would have fewer data points than the whole data set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case others run across this foolish user error.

The problem was that `CategoryDataset` only allows one data point per "category", and in my case, "category" was a `java.util.Date` captured from the web server log. Apparently, nearly half of my dates were duplicates and so part of the data set overwrote the other half, leaving a subset of the data.

That should have been totally obvious to me at the outset, because that is exactly how a category dataset works.

Anyhow, simply changing the category plot series's "category expression" from `$F{DATE}` to `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` gave each datum a unique category which makes everything work.